# How can I open Excel from another Office Application without setting references?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

From Word and Outlook, I'm trying to open open Excel using GetObject method but I need to set the references first.  I receive "Compile error: User-defined type not defined".  In order to manually fix this, I need to go to Tools>References>Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library.  Is there a way to not have to do the manual step of setting the reference?

I access the same files from different sessions (local session, citrix, VM ware) that have different versions of Excel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/working-with-other-applications/controlling-one-microsoft-office-application-from-another

Code so far

```
Sub Macro1()
'
    Dim Excel As Object

    Dim wkbkXLBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wkSheet As Excel.worksheet

    Set Excel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Excel Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox ("Excel was not found")

    End If

    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried a `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` instead of GetObject?

Comment: I think that your problem is coming from the `Excel.xxxx` in variable declaration.  As with Excel object, dim as object and try???

Comment: @fbueckert arguably `CreateObject` could be used in the `If Excel Is Nothing` branch, to create a new instance when an existing one doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

If you're not adding the reference to the type library, you can't use the early-bound types defined in that type library.

> ```
> Dim wkbkXLBook As Excel.Workbook
> Dim wkSheet As Excel.worksheet
> ```

`Excel` is the programmatic name of the Excel type library, and `Workbook` is the name of a class defined in that library. Same for `Worksheet`. Since Excel isn't referenced, VBA can't resolve these types, and you get a compile error.

You need to work with late-bound code, i.e. in the dark, without *IntelliSense*, autocompletion, or parameter quick-info, and without making any typos - lest you run into run-time error 438 and 1004.

"Late-bound" means "resolved at run-time". Whenever you declare something `As Object`, that's precisely what happens:

```
Dim wkbkXLBook As Object
Dim wkSheet As Object
```

You can't use any of the Excel types unless you reference the Excel type library. That includes any `xl*` constant, too.

> ```
> Dim Excel As Object
> ```

I'd warmly recommend renaming this to e.g. `xlApp`.

Watch out for implicit object references:

```
Dim someRange As Object
Set someRange = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

The above will work, but will also leak the `ActiveWorkbook` object, its `Worksheets` collection, and the `Worksheet` object retrieved; these leaked objects can (and often *do*) prevent the `EXCEL.EXE` process from correctly shutting down, even after executing `xlApp.Quit` and `Set xlApp = Nothing`: avoid double-dot referencing objects like this. Do this instead:

```
Dim books As Object
Set books = xlApp.Workbooks

Dim wb As Object
Set wb = books("workbook name")

Dim wbSheets As Object
Set wbSheets = wb.Worksheets

Dim ws As Object
Set ws = wbSheets("sheet name")

Dim rng As Object
Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
```

With every object involved explicitly scoped to the local procedure, everything should be fine.